# docker swarm - how to make that there is AT MOST 1 replica

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm quite new to docker swarm and running into an issue:

I'm trying to set uptime-kuma up in my swarm. All the data of the containers is stored in a ceph cluster. The problem is, that uptime-kuma uses a sqlite database, which doesn't allow concurrent access. So every time the container is rescheduled (e.g. moved to another node) the database gets corrupted and I have to repair it manually.

Is there a way to make sure that there is at most one replica of the container running? So that docker would have to shutdown the old one first before starting the new one? I now I will get a short downtime that way, but I would prefer that over having to manually restore the database once in a while.

Thank you!

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  uptime-kuma:
    image: louislam/uptime-kuma:1.21.1
    volumes:
      - /mnt/ceph/uptime-kuma:/app/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
       - 3001:3001
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

Comment: Given the configuration you show, Swarm should not allow duplicates. Both UpdateConfig and RollbackConfig have a default of stop-first, and RestartConfig should only apply after a service has already failed.
And exception might be if the swarm itself is not healthy - if docker daemon on a worker node crashes / stops responding to managers, tasks will be left running, but manager nodes can notice the missing worker and reschedule tasks on other nodes.